# What does -14-generic stand for when I run the command uname -r in my Ubuntu system?

Tags: kernel, 22.04, versions

I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 system and when I run the command "uname -r" I get :

6.5.0-14-generic

I'm guessing my Ubuntu is based on the kernel version 6.5.0 but I don't understand that -14-generic...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is generic version of ubuntu ? how it differes from other versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401410/what-exactly-is-generic-version-of-ubuntu-how-it-differes-from-other-versions)

Comment: And for the "-14" part, it (build number) is just part of the version number like the 6 (major), 5 (minor), and 0 (patch) are.

Comment: @Daniel T, I know the concept of major-minor-patch. The problem here is that there is a fourth value...that -14- and then generic that I don't understand. If I visit the linux kernel archives I see MAJOR-MINOR-PATCH versioning...so all I know is that my Ubuntu is based on linux kernel 6.5.0

Comment: See earthmeLon's answer for the explanation

Comment: -14 tells you the update/upgrade & security-fix level...   If patches are made to 20-22 for example; it's pretty clear to know if you're using the -14 you don't have those security patches applied (ie. haven't updated your system).  The -14 is useful if you're scanning Ubuntu Security notices, or list of patches in notices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *sort* of [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/).

```
MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-RELEASE+BUILD
```

The portion that says `generic` refers to your CPU architecture.  So if you're on `1.1.1-1-generic`, you could upgrade to `1.1.1-2-generic` or `1.1.2-1-generic`, as those are upgrades.  Typically, you'd say you're on `1.1.1-1`, or `6.5.0-14` version of the Kernel, for generic architecture.

So, your kernel version is the portion without the "generic" text.

---

Instead of asking 'around' your problem, you should tell us what you're actually trying to do.  If something is telling you need a specific kernel version, what is that something and what are you trying to do?  ~[XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @earthmeLon, so let's say that I gotta download a kernel version from the archive on the internet that match "6.5.0-14-generic". What version should I download ? Just 6.5.0 ?

Comment: This kernel is not pre-release, It's in default repositories but appears to be outdated, as far as I can see 6.5.0-15 is the recent version. It's the generic kernel means other kernels like lowlatency or realtime kernels are derived from the generic kernel via special patches. I use a lowlatency kernel which ends with `-lowlatency`, not `-generic`. You should not download anything, just run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to install the newer version.

Comment: @mook765, I don't have to download the kernel. I just wanted to know what is the kernel version in the online archive corresponding to the "6.5.0-14-generic". What is that ? https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/

Comment: It's not exactly Sementic Versioning, but the spirit exists.  All 6.5.0-PRERELEASES are pre-releases for 6.5.1 ;)

Comment: @Kode1000 there isn't any such version, as part of the work any distro does in packaging kernels is patching them (backporting security fixes, maybe some extra patches not yet merged upstream). You need those patches as well, and for that you will have to use the distro's preferred method for obtaining source code.