# What happens if I boot a low-latency kernel?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I am very interested in what low latency mode is. It appears in the "Advanced Options" of the GRUB menu. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Check this question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/126664/why-choose-a-low-latency-kernel-over-a-generic-or-realtime-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to how your CPU handles processes. If you are booting Linux on an older laptop with a 2 core CPU, I would boot low-latency.

Basically latency is the delay before data is moved based on the instructions on how the data is moved. So lower the latency, the quicker data is being Processed/sent/received.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to simply answer future questions, and not ramble on about stuff that has nothing to do with the question.