# What's the difference between 'generic' and 'aws' kernel?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

Actually, my question is much more general.

I would like to update the kernel to get some recent security updates.

```
ubuntu@ip-14-0-50-189:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-image
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-image is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-image-3.13.0-87-generic 3.13.0-87.133
  linux-image-3.13.0-139-generic 3.13.0-139.188
  linux-image-4.4.0-111-lowlatency 4.4.0-111.134~14.04.1
  linux-image-4.4.0-111-generic 4.4.0-111.134~14.04.1
  linux-image-4.4.0-1011-aws 4.4.0-1011.11
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-image' has no installation candidate
```

I need one of the 4.4.0 kernels -- `generic`, `lowlatency` or `aws`. The host is running in EC2, so I'm guess that `aws` would be an acceptable choice. But I don't have any actual information about the different types.

Where can I find information about the different versions I'm being offered here?

Why are `generic` and `lowlatency` version `4.4.0-111.134` while `aws` is `4.4.0-1011.1`?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126664/why-choose-a-low-latency-kernel-over-a-generic-or-realtime-one