# Is audio latency reduced on Ubuntu Studio versus Windows 10?

Tags: alsa, jack

Although I'm still working out how to best use ALSA or Jack on Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2, my question at the moment is simply whether the native audio latency is different or better on Ubuntu vs Windows 10, all other things like application in use, ethernet cable to router and audio interface used being the same?
The application actually being used is Sonobus and I have it working on ALSA but not Jack.
I do get occasional audio glitches but changing the audio buffer size from 64 to 128 to 160 only seems to fix it for a while.

https://sonobus.net/linux.html

Comment: One question is whether, given the same set of connections/external hardware and internet bandwidth, Linux has less overhead that contributes to latency.  As far as the specifics:  I'm trying to do online music jamming with Sonobus. Laptop is connected by ethernet cable to router.  Centurylink DSL with 35 up, 5 down.
The four people I regularly connect with all have significantly greater bandwidth so my latency to the session is a problem.  Even a 5 millisecond improvement would make the switch to Ubuntu worth the effort.

Comment: So far I've just tried ALSA since I don't yet understand Jack well enough.  But really for this post, it's a pretty high-level question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Studio, unlike any other variant, comes with `low-latency` kernel specifically for the audio recording features.

Theoretically it is always better suited for the task than any generic kernel, irrespective of the OS family.

This old Q&A has amazing insights and a wealth of information that is for the most part still valid nowadays: [Why choose a low latency kernel over a generic or real-time kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126664/why-choose-a-low-latency-kernel-over-a-generic-or-real-time-kernel)